# Creating a threaded graphic model similar to the Apple Watch clock

Tags: html, css, vuejs2

I am creating a donut chart with HTML and CSS, with the same visual model that Apple Watch uses in its watches. Later, I will feed real data to each of the 3 goals in the model.

Below is the model of the donut chart used:

[image]

To start development in the simplest way, I started with the css properties, which are `radial-gradient`, and `conic-gradient`, where by increasing or decreasing the transparency of the radial-gradient, I can manipulate it as if it were a goal from 0 to 100.

However, I'm having trouble making the starting and ending edges of each goal. You can see in the first image that at the beginning of the graph and at the end, instead of being a straight edge, it's a rounded edge.

Below is the code I ran to get the closest similarity. You can see that I can't manipulate the beginning and end of each color, exactly the same as the model proposed in the image.

Has anyone ever needed to create something similar, but with html css and javascript, or can you help me provide an alternative where I can get as close as possible to applying the starting and ending borders?

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #1c1c1e;
}

.progress-bar {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 2s;
}
.relativo {
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.progress-bar-two {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 2s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

.progress-bar-three {
  width: 118px;
  height: 118px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 41px;
  transition: all 2s;
  left: 41px;
}
```

```html
<div class="relativo">
  <div class="progress-bar" style="background: 
    radial-gradient(closest-side, #1c1c1e 84%, transparent 85% 100%),
    conic-gradient(#ec113b 35%, #3b191a 0);">
    
  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar-two" style="background: 
      radial-gradient(closest-side, #1c1c1e 79%, transparent 80% 100%),
      conic-gradient(#3cdd03 10%, #203919 0);">
    
  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar-three" style="background: 
      radial-gradient(closest-side, #1c1c1e 72%, transparent 75% 100%),
      conic-gradient(#00c3df 50%, #17343a 0);">
    
  </div>
```

Comment: You'll want to use `<path />` SVG element, as it allows setting of [stroke-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-width) and [stroke-linecap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-linecap). You might find this article on [how to decompose circles into paths](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/03/svg-circle-decomposition-paths/) useful. What you've done so far has no chances of achieving the desired output. If you want the rounded linecaps, that is, of course.

Comment: I stand corrected by Temani's answer, which uses`:before` and `:after` to place small circles at the edge of the circle segment. I still think an `<svg>` based solution would be cleaner and more appropriate for a vue app. It would also provide complete control over the animation (e.g: cancelling, reversing, chaining, dynamic duration, etc.)